# Magento - Order confirmations/invoices ends up as spam

Tags: magento, html-email

Alot of my customers are getting their Invoices and Confirmations as Spam, is there a way to get around this? I've been googeling the subject but with no luck. The emails I'm sending out now is mostly default mangeto html bodys with minor changes.

Comment: the problem most likely to be related to the domain/ip... check if the domain/ip is blacklisted and so on... also get your sysadmin to look at the mail server settings/headers sent and so on.

Comment: Post your header from a received email. This will include why spam flag set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a very good article from Inchoo on how to configure both Magento and server to avoid your emails get into spam folder (also check a comment from Fooman below the article)

http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/fight-spam-emails/

Answer (score 0):

Changing these 2 things solved the problem for me:

1. Under System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> System -> Mail Sending Settings: set 'Set Return-Path' to 'Specified' and enter a Return-Path E-mail.
2. In app/code/core/Zend/Mime.php change LINELENGTH from 200 to 100.